# What we call tests that we can work from home?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

For designer's and writer's jobs, candidates get tasks that they can work from home and later they submit it. Can we call that type of tests 'an aptitude test?'

Comment: An aptitude test tests the aptitude of the test subject relative to a particular skill.  What does "aptitude" mean?

Comment: A test that you take home was always called a "take-home test" when I was in school.